# Struct In Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I learn solidity
in struct chapter I try this code , and I get book_id ok , when I want to return title ,and I change uint
to string in code give me error

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract test {
   struct Book { 
      string title;
      string author;
      uint book_id;
   }
   Book book;

   function setBook() public {
      book = Book('Learn Java', 'TP', 1);
   }
   function getBookId() public view returns (uint) {
      return book.book_id;
   }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

When you are working with reference types (such as `string`), you need to specify their location. Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/types.html#reference-types

In case of a function return value, the only location that makes sense is memory.

You specify the location after the data type, so in your case `returns (string memory)`.

```
function getBookTitle() public view returns (string memory) {
    return book.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new function to return the target data type depending on what you want.

In this case, you want to return `title` it has data type is `string` so you should create a new function to return `string` like this.

```
function getTitle() public view returns (string memory) {
  return book.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add a getter in your contract , add a new function chose any name implement it like this way:

```
  function getTitleId() public view returns (string memory) {
   return book.title; }
```

your function must be "public view" because you just wanna read data from the blockchain. and return a memory string (reference type) check solidity doc